# Rewriting http://www.mysite.com/mypage.asp to http://www.mysite.com/

Tags: url, iis-7, asp-classic, url-rewriting

Is there a way to rewrite http://www.mysite.com/mypage.asp to http://www.mysite.com/ (ie. hide the script name) without causing a redirect loop? The default page on my site is doing a redirect based on the hostname, in other words if the browser requests http://www.site1.com the normal index.asp loads, however if the browser requests http://www.site2.com then the script redirects to http://www.site2.com/layout.asp. What I'm trying to achieve is to hide the "layout.asp" part while still loading that page... is that even possible with a URL rewrite?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use custom error pages to do URL rewriting in Classic ASP, as an example see http://asp.johnavis.com/blog/default.asp?id=19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default.asp:

```
<%
<!-- #include file="mypage.asp" -->
%>
```

Comment: Hmmm that's an interesting option; I hadn't considered this approach, but it might be worthwhile to explore it. Using server.execute rather than an #include might allow me to avoid the inclusion of the full code of the destination page.... nice one. Thanks :) I'm still hoping to see a response to whether it's possible with a URL rewrite, as well...

Comment: @Frank there is a rewrite component for iis/classic asp, it is used in my company, but I don't know how this works.